# How do I map my gamepad to Half-Life?

Tags: controllers, half-life

So I tried mapping my Xbox 360 controller to the original Half-Life, and no good. Must I use a third party software to map the keys?

Comment: Is this for *Half-Life*, *Half-Life: Source*, or *Half-Life 2, Episode 1*?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Half-Life

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this I think.
I recommand you to use JoyToKey. It's a third party software to map keyboard keys on your pad buttons.
[image]
I use it to play to Binding Of Isaac with my Xbox360 gamepad and it works fine.
You can find the software [here](http://joytokey.net/en/).

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

Official controller support was added to Half-Life 1 on [November 17, 2023](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/70/view/6941797379568863069) as part of the game's [25th Anniversary Update](https://www.half-life.com/en/halflife25/).